# Python обработать двумерный массив

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x, список, xlrd

Есть файл Excel, в файле две колонки, в первом артикул товара, во втором имя файла с картинкой товара.


Задача: переименовать файлы по артиклу(из первой колонки)


Данные из Excel я получаю с помощью xlrd в двумерном списке [[103932.0, 'a63-1.png'], [103948.0, 'a63-2.png'], [103964.0, 'a63-3.png'], [103980.0, 'a63-4.png']]


У меня трудности с обращением к вложенному в список списку и циклу(((

```
import xlrd

#открываем файл
rb = xlrd.open_workbook(r'c:\Users\nva\Downloads\keaz.xls',formatting_info=True)

#выбираем активный лист
sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)

#Получаем значения ячеек
vals = [sheet.row_values(rownum) for rownum in range(sheet.nrows)]
```

Comment: Что значит "трудности"? Какие конкретно ошибки возникают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было бы хорошо, если бы вы написали, какие именно трудности у вас возникают. Следующий код должен работать без каких-либо проблем

```
for val in vals:
    code = val[0]
    file_name = val[1]
```